# How to access base class from within subclass?

Tags: c#

I have an abstract class called BaseMonster. This "base" class holds several values, such as float dyingTime =2, that will be the same for all monster subclasses. But since there are a lot of values like this, I didn't want to pass them into the object call when you "new" a monster.

So my question is: for subclass Ghoul, which inherits from BaseMonster, how can I pull the value for dyingTime from BaseMonster?

EDIT: To clarify, I need to have these values in Ghoul in order to run certain movement calculations that are different than the regular BaseMonster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should study the concepts of inheritance (BaseMonster being a base class for Ghoul) and access modifiers which govern which fields, methods and property are accessible from where.

You can find all access modifiers [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx)

Also see this simple example:

```
public class Base
{
    private float a;
    protected float b;
    public float c;

}


public class Sub : Base
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
       float x = base.a; // Error cannot access private member a

       // Note that putting base before b and c here is optional
       // though it does help with naming conflicts 
       // if Sub would also have a member b you could differentiate the two
       // using this.b and base.b
       float y = base.b; // Works
       float z = base.c; // Works
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't have a guide book or anything for c#, so my learning has been very ad-hoc...but this is a great example.